# How to get validation erros from multi models in sequelize + node.js

Tags: node.js, postgresql, express, transactions, sequelize.js

I'm trying to create models with including related models. Then validation is failed i get only 1 error instead of all fails of validation.
at example is

```
[
    {
        "loads": {
            "name": "Name is required"
        }
    }
]
```

How can i get all validation fails with all related models? Like

```
[
    {
        "model1": {
            "name": "Name is required"
        }
    },
    {
        "model2": {
            "name": "Name is required"
        }
    },
    {
        "model3": {
            "name": "Name is required"
        }
    },
    {
        "etc": {
            "name": "Name is required"
        }
    }
]
```

Here is my router function:

```
router.post('/', [checkAuth], async (req, res) => {
    let {
        name="",
        weight="",
        volume="",
        packing_type="",
        price_request="",
        note="",
        visible="",
        Origin={city_id: '', date_from: ''}, // Origin object
        Destination={city_id: ''}, // Destination object
    } = req.body;


    result = await db.transaction((t) => {
        return LoadModel.create({
            user_id: user_id,
            name: name,
            weight: weight,
            volume: volume,
            packing_type: packing_type,
            price_request: price_request,
            note: note,
            visible: visible,
            origin: Origin,
            destination: Destination,
        },{ include: [
            OriginModel, DestinationModel
        ], transaction: t})
    }).then(result => {
        res.status(201).json(result);
    }).catch(Sequelize.ValidationError, (err) => {
      res.status(400).json(err.errors.map(item => {
            return {
                [item.instance._modelOptions.tableName]: {[item.path]: item.message}
            };
        })); // How can i get all validation errors for returning it?
    }).catch(badError => {
        res.status(500).json(badError);
    })
    validateErrors.catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
    }) 
});
```

Maybe there is a way to return validation errors from promise to global object? Or something else...

Comment: Code looks fine, can you share your schema definition.

Comment: Code works fine, but he cant display me all validation errors. Only one by one. If first model throw validation error it will display it. I want see all validations error in a row

Comment: I understand that and code above should be working fine which is why I asked to see the schema definition.